# Error: error getting canonical path to source HTML file "index.html" in rust

Tags: rust, webassembly, yew

I've just started a client side project in yew(rust frontend framework).
I've just written a few lines of code and I'm getting the following error.

> Error: "error getting canonical path to source HTML file "index.html".

My cargo.toml, main.rs and index.html and error message files are as follows : 

cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "yew-app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
yew = "0.19"
```

main.rs

```
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
    html! {
        <h1> { "Hello World" } </h1>
    }
}

fn main(){
    yew::start_app::<App>();
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

terminal command and error message :

```
trunk build
Error: error getting canonical path to source HTML file "index.html"

Caused by:
    The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
```

index.html file is located at the root of the folder. 
How can i fix this error?

Comment: Hello, do you have  create index.html at the **root of the project**?

Comment: Please provide the exact directory/file structure you have. We can assume `main.rs` is within the `src` directory, but where did you put `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ..
cd <back to root folder>
trunk build
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @Tyler2P do you really need an explanation for cd? That's exagerated.

Comment: @Doma, your answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

oot directory of the app in Rust is the path of the directory which you created using

```html
cargo new yew-app

or

mkdir yew-app
cargo init yew-app
```

In this directory cargo.toml file will exist and it is from this directory that you should invoke "trunk" commannds.
And index.html should reside in this root directory as well.